# How can I append text with table tr using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have got a assignment to implement knockout js to my application. I have a table like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Iphone
        </td>
        <td>
            SmartPhone
        </td>
        <td>
            50000
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are three textbox for creation of this field.

```
<div id="create">
    <input data-bind="value: Name" id="name"/>
    <input data-bind="value: Category" id="category"/>
    <input data-bind="value: Prize" id="prize"/>
</div>
```

When I am typing on this textboxes i want to show this on the table as a new tr.. How can I do this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BJQgw/)

Reference [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is define a viewmodel that contains the data for an individual item, and another viewmodel that contains the rest of the interactions (list of items, how to add new ones, etc).

```
var Item = function (Name, Category, Price) {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable(Name);
    self.Category = ko.observable(Category);
    self.Price = ko.observable(Price);
}    

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.ItemToAdd = ko.observable(new Item());

    self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addItem = function (item) {
        self.Items.push(item);      
        self.ItemToAdd(new Item());
    }
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

vm.addItem(new Item('Iphone', 'SmartPhone', 50000));

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

In your html, your table body will look like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"/>
        <td data-bind="text: Category"/>
        <td data-bind="text: Price"/>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

what this does is loops through each item in the Itemlist and creates a `<tr>` for each one and binds the values of the Item object in the observableArray to the `<td>` elements.

to add new items to the table in your markup:

```
<div data-bind="with: ItemToAdd">
    <input data-bind="value: Name" id="name"/>
    <input data-bind="value: Category" id="category"/>
    <input data-bind="value: Price" id="price"/>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.addItem">Add</button>
</div>
```

this sets the context of the div element to a new Item object, and when you click the Add button, it calls the parent context's (ViewModel) addItem function, and automatically passes the context item for the div element (ItemToAdd).  Then its just a matter of pushing it on to the observableArray and the table will update with the new item.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJQgw/4/

if this was a for-real application, you would perform some sort of validation prior to adding the item to the list (preferably using knockout-validation)